# jitterdodge positions points outside of corresponding boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

Why does `position_jitterdodge` place points outside of an associated fill boxplot? Below, see that there are 'circles' that should be associated with `cyl=4` that are instead positioned with `cyl=6`. I would like all 'circles' to be positioned with the boxplot for `cyl=4`, how can this be accomplished?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mpg %>%
  filter(class == "midsize") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=class, y=hwy, fill=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(cyl)),position=position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Use `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)`. Certain points (the outliers) are being plotted twice, once from `geom_point` and once from `geom_boxplot`.

Comment: @bdemarest This works.